# Creating Many To Many Relationships using Fluent API in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-interface

Using Entity Framework's API I keep coming across the following two ways to map many to many relationships? I have never used the second option... what is the difference?

Option 1:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasMany( p => p.Lessons)
    .WithMany();
```

Option 2:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
.HasMany(p => p.Lessons)
.WithMany() 
.Map(m =>
{
    m.MapLeftKey("Id");
    m.MapRightKey("Id");
    m.ToTable("StudentAndLessons");
});
```

What exactly does `MapLeftKey` and `MapRightKey` do? When would you use it and what benefits are gained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `.Map(...)` method in this scenario allows you to define the name of the junction table as well as the names of the columns in said junction table.  `MapLeftKey(string)` would set the name of the FK field of the junction table referencing the key for `Student`.  Likewise, `MapRightKey(string)` sets the name of the FK field of the junction table referencing the key of the `Lesson` table.  A more descriptive usage is as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Lessons)
    .WithMany() 
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
        m.MapRightKey("LessonId");
        m.ToTable("StudentLesson");
    });
```

Without using the `.Map` method, EF will decide how to name the junction table and the associated FK columns