# Convert SQL statement to Linq Statement (3 table left joins + where)

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, left-join, where-clause

This is the working sql I need converted to Linq:

```
select * from dbo.Pod p
 left join dbo.PodEvent pe on p.PodId = pe.Pod_PodId
 left join dbo.Event e on pe.Event_EventId = e.EventId
where e.StartDateTime >= '2014-12-24 09:00:00.000' 
  and e.EndDateTime <= '2014-12-24 14:30:00.000'
```

I have been trying suggestions from different posts all day and this is the best I could do and the issue is that its an inner join, where I need it to be a left join so I can get all the pods for given time interval:

```
List<Pod> pods =
    (from p in db.Pods
     join pe in db.PodEvents on p.PodId equals pe.Pod.PodId
     join e in db.Events on pe.Event.EventId equals e.EventId
     where
     e.StartDateTime == userInfo.StartDateTime
      &&
     e.EndDateTime <= userInfo.EndDateTime
     select p).ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: Try investigating a `GroupJoin`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried a few examples but then I have issues converting my results to a list... would you know of any material?

Comment: Maybe this link would be helpful for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin

Comment: [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is also a great tool for converting to/from Linq.

Comment: Use this http://www.sqltolinq.com/downloads to convert your sql queries to LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the `WHERE` filter in your SQL  will effectively render the Left Outer Join redundant, as any failed JOINS will be [filtered out by the WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297231/where-clause-vs-on-when-using-join), you could use this fact to manually project an INNER JOIN through the junction table with no navigation (and the performance is likely to be awful):

```
var pods = db.Events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime >= userInfo.StartDateTime
                                 && e.EndDateTime < userInfo.EndDateTime)
                     .Join(db.PodEvents, 
                            e => e.EventID, 
                            pe => pe.EventId,
                            new (e, pe) => {
                               Event = e,
                               PodEvent = pe,
                               Pod = db.Pods.Single(p => p.PodId == pe.PodID)
                            })
                      .SelectMany(x => x.Pod);
```

However, given that you have navigation through `pe.Event.EventId`, why not fix the navigation on all three tables, which will allow the much simpler:

```
var pods = db.Events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime >= userInfo.StartDateTime
                                && e.EndDateTime < userInfo.EndDateTime)
                    .SelectMany(e => e.PodEvents.Select(pe => pe.Pod));
```

Also, if `PodEvent` is just a Junction Table (`EventId, PodId`) - by modelling this as a Many:Many in EF you can avoid the `PodEvent` junction entity altogether, and `Event` and `Pod` will become directly navigable.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! I have the ability to convert my junction table to many::many relationship, and I will. You mentioned a navigation issue, any idea how I could go about resolving it? or will removing the junction table fix the issue?

Comment: In Sql, you must have the junction table, but in EF, provided you just need the N:N keys in the table, you can navigate through it as if it was invisible - See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5418534/314291 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954520/creating-many-to-many-relationships-using-fluent-api-in-entity-framework

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. Do you mean that if I do everything through EF (which I am), then I don't need my junction table?
or
I need my junction table on the sql side but I can have EF think it doesn't exist?

Comment: Assuming Code first, this will create a N:N junction table in Sql, and and inform EF of the relationship: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26638150/314291